# Создание exe файла не загружается библиотека open cv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Стоит Анаконда 3.6. В коде `import cv2` и `import numpy as np`, включение ВЭБ камеры.

Запускаю с помощью командной строки `python.exe` все работает.

Создаю с помощью `pyinstaller` приложение, при запуске готового приложения выводит ошибку в строке `import cv`. Возможно это исправить?

Comment: попробуй проверить синтаксис команды, не получится – ничего неожиданного, за компиляцией Python в исполняемый файл обычно следует большое количество ошибок, если же тебе всё же надо его компилировать, попробуй обновить модуль pip, и переустановить pyinstaller или опять же, повторюсь, проверить синтаксис и расположение файла.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то приложение не создавалось потому что находилось в директории vertual lenv в PyCharm. Когда перенес файл code.py на диск C:\ и с этого расположения запустил pyinstaller то приложение успешно создалось.